# Cuda 5.2 in Matlab R2015b and 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, matlab, cuda

Test code

```
X = rand(10,'single');
G = gpuArray(X);
classUnderlying(G);
```

but I get from the second line

```
Error using gpuArray
An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
```

This suggests me that I have a problem with drivers in my Ubuntu 14.04.

### Unsuccessful settings in 14.04

To avoid complications from other packages, I run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` before each installation.

1. `build-essential nvidia-cuda-toolkit libcuda1-352 nvidia-libopencl1-352 nvidia-opencl-icd-352 nvidia-352`
2. `nvidia-current nvidia-settings`

I think I have a dependency problem. 
I am using GTX 960. 
I heard that only Ubuntu 15.04 has drivers for Nvidia 9** at the moment.

I think there is no descent support for GPU and Matlab in 14.04. 
The situation seems to be much more robust in 15.10 with Matlab because of official and noveau support. 
A separate case about it in the thread [Cuda 5.2 in Matlab R2015b and 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/715789/25388)

---

Which packages are only necessary to run the test code with Cuda 5.2 in Matlab R2015b?

Comment: This might be a **Matlab** support question, more than an **Nvidia** driver / **Ubuntu** issue ..

Comment: @david6 This is Ubuntu issue where the community drivers are so disorganized.

Comment: It's unclear if the driver got installed cleanly. Can you check nvidia-setting to varify that. Also, nvidia-352 is not a community driver, and I am not sure why install `nvidia-current`, which apparently depends on `nvidia-304`.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yes, you are right. I updated some characteristics of my nvidia-settings in the body of the latest post for 15.10.